# How to increase memory_limit in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web-config, memory-limit

Recently I set my site on my server(http://abc.hostname.com/sitename/) and I get following error:

```
It seems like the memory_limit on the server is too low for the fade on load feature.
```

I add the following code in wp-config.php to solve this error:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' ); also
ini_set("memory_limit","60M");
```

But the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

To increase memory limit .All you have to do is find line number 36 or 37 in wp-config file and add the following code there.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

The problem will be solved.I think you are placing above code on somewhere else in wp-config file.Please add above code on line 36 or 37 only.